# covert string to uppercase except the string in () in php

Tags: php

How to covert string to uppercase except the string in () in php

For example: `abc(abc)(ABC)(abc)abc` >>>change to>>> `ABC(abc)(ABC)(abc)ABC`

```
....
$str = 'abc(abc)(ABC)(abc)abc abc(abc)';
function toupper($str) {

???

}
....
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `$test` and `$_SESSION['test'][$i]`?

Comment: What has the converting string to do with the if statement? How to they related to each other? Some more info would be appreciated.

Comment: How about if the $str like this >>> $str = 'abc(abc)(ABC)(abc)abc abc(abc)';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the string pattern remains consistent,

```
function toUpper($str)
{
   $exp = explode('(', $str);
   $to_up = strtoupper($exp[0]);
   $inside_brackets = '('.$exp[1];
   return $to_up.$inside_brackets;
}

echo toUpper("abc(def)");
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3yMtFJ)

Comment: @LinkinTED: Invalid edit..the closing bracket is missing for a reason

Comment: Yeah, saw it too late. Already rolled it back. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: is this work for the string  'abc(def)av(vgg)'

Comment: @next2u No it wont. And there is no information from the OP regarding the pattern of the string that will be used. Hence, `Provided the string pattern remains consistent,`

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
$str = 'abc(abc)';
$pos = strpos($str,'(');
$str1 = strtoupper(substr($str,0,$pos)); 
echo $str1.substr($str,$pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace_callback();

Here is an example :

```
<?php 
 function callback($matches)
 {
      return strtoupper($matches[1]).'('.$matches[2].')';
 }

 $str = 'test(args)';

 echo preg_replace_callback('#(.+)\((.+)\)?#','callback',$str);
```

?>